# Oracle Cloud and Docker

Tags: oracle, cloud

I am trying to run my docker on Oracle Cloud instance.
In the past (dedicated server with public IP), I used to run this command to bind my container: docker run -d -p 80:80 image

But now, it doesn't work anymore.
I checked my network interfaces, and I am getting confused, because I cannot see my public IP. How to fix this issue?

1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
inet6 ::1/128 scope host
valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever

2: ens3: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 9000 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP group default qlen 1000
link/ether 02:00:17:00:8e:77 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
inet 10.0.0.4/24 brd 10.0.0.255 scope global ens3
valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
inet6 fe80::17ff:fe00:8e77/64 scope link
valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever

3: docker0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state DOWN group default
link/ether 02:42:cc:94:7a:d9 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
inet 172.17.0.1/16 brd 172.17.255.255 scope global docker0
valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
inet6 fe80::42:ccff:fe94:7ad9/64 scope link
valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever

Answer (score 0):

I can't give you a complete answer without knowing what exactly is your network setup.
However, all information can be found [here](https://docs.oracle.com/en-us/iaas/Content/Network/Tasks/managingpublicIPs.htm).

To summarize, for instances in Oracle Cloud Infrastructure to be accessible from the outside there is a set of prerequisites:

- Create a VCN and a public subnet
- Create an Internet Gateway in your VCN
- Add that internet Gateway to the subnet route table
- Create an instance (only the private IP will be visible inside of your instance
  in your case, it is 10.0.0.4.
- Assign a public IP to your instance (in reality OCI links the public IP to the
  private one and not to the instance itself).

If you already have a public subnet you should have seen an "assign public IP" checkbox while creating the instance.

Please feel free to add more details about your setup.